# Tool for testing Schema.org markup

Tags: testing, markup, schema.org

Does anyone know of a good tool to test Schema.org (http://schema.org/) markup?

The Google Rich Snippet tool does not support it properly. Even with the correct markup given, it says "Insufficient data to generate the preview."

**update:** Now the [Google Rich Snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) supports some [schema.org](http://schema.org/) markups.

Comment: I'd love to see something I can use at least on localhost :)

Comment: Just FYI, Google has a response to this, and acknowledge the Rich Snippet tool needs to be updated here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1211158

They state "Currently, you can use the testing tool to see what information Google can extract from your pages. We're working on updating the tool so you can see how content marked up with schema.org might appear in search results."

Comment: thanks for the information, but this address exactly my question if there is another tool to help.

Comment: Direct link to the Rich Snippets Testing Tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: Here's a chrome extension that will pull out any microdata on a page. It doesn't require any external services, so it works on localhost and offline. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/microdatareveal/olapakiakkblfdaajcifgldandnikpdh?hl=en-US

Comment: Related question on [softwarerecs.se] (checking Microdata online, possibly with Schema.org support): [**Online Microdata parser**](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13674/60)

Answer (score 22):

This one came to my attention recently. [linter.structured-data.org](http://linter.structured-data.org)

I like that it generates a preview when the Google Rich Snippet tool reports "Insufficient data to generate the preview." The structured-data tool also generates a more structured, almost graphical result, which makes the results a bit easier to understand.

Comment: Note that this linter is not as strict as Google Rich Snippet and it won't report missing required attributes as errors

Answer (score 16):

The [**microdata-tool**](http://krofdrakula.github.com/microdata-tool/) jQuery plugin.

Included in your markup it displays the metadata it is able to extract. Thus it's ideal for using it offline or on localhost. 
Although it's work in progress, it supports many (if not all, I'm not sure) of the schema.org metadata.

Answer (score 5):

[Mida](http://lawrencewoodman.github.com/mida/) supports the full schema.org standard and would therefore be worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Bings Validator now: https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/diagnostics/markup/validator

Comment: That link does not resolve to a validator tool.