# Validating your implementation of Schema.org Microdata?

Tags: validation, schema.org, microdata

Is there any way to validate that an implementation of Microdata (using Schema.org) is correct? Eyeballing the HTML is not really the best test … :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah...

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Also: [Tool for testing Schema.org markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496114/tool-for-testing-schema-org-markup?rq=1)

Why does my google-fu always improver markedly right after asking a questions? WHY?!?!?!